# Nokogiri outputs different strings on different systems

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

- I am reading a local .html file using the following line:

  `myDoc = File.open("Ina.html") { |f| Nokogiri::HTML(f) }`
- I get a Node using xpath and then I simply print it

  `divNode = myDoc.at_xpath('//div[@id="mw-content-text"]/p[1]')
   puts divNode`

**Fragment of Output on one system:** Using ruby 2.3

`<p><b>Ina:</b> Ñe’êpehê , ñe’ẽtéva rire (aha´aína)</p>`

**Fragment of Output on another system:** Using ruby 2.1

```
<p><b>Ina:</b> &Atilde;&#145;e&acirc;&#128;&#153;&Atilde;&ordf;peh&Atilde;&ordf; , &Atilde;&plusmn;e&acirc;&#128;&#153;&aacute;&ordm;&frac12;t&Atilde;&copy;va rire (aha&Acirc;&acute;a&Atilde;&shy;na)</p>
```

Any thoughts on what is going on with the encoding? All the suggestions of forcing the encoding and/or specifying the encoding have not been successful.

Comment: For reference, here's the url of the html I am working with [link] (https://gn.wiktionary.org/wiki/Ina)

Comment: Maybe this is a language problem, one system may support other one is not.

Comment: Hmm. it could be but when I print the actual strings directly, like puts "<String>", there is no problem. I am thinking that it could also have to do with how Nokogiiri decodes the html file.

Comment: What versions of Nokogiri are on each system? And have you attempted to parse the uri into a readable? (`URI.parse`)

Comment: Please read "[mcve]". We need a minimal sample of the input HTML that demonstrates the problem. What OS and LOCALE settings are the systems in question?

Comment: Instead of `myDoc = File.open("Ina.html") { |f| Nokogiri::HTML(f) }` simply use `my_doc = Nokogiri::HTML(File.read('Ina.html'))`. Note, in Ruby we don't use camelCase for variables, they're snake_case.

Answer (score 0):

Well,  I fixed the problem but I still don't fully understand why this way would not work.

So, the solution was to simply read the whole .html file and then instantiate the nokogiri object by parsing the the string of the file.

```
  file = File.open(outputFolder + "/" + htmlName,"rb")
  content = file.read
  doc = Nokogiri::HTML.parse(content,nil, "UTF-8")
```

To me,this was equivalent to either one of the statements I tried:

- `myDoc = File.open("Ina.html") { |f| Nokogiri::HTML(f) }`
- `myDoc = File.open("Ina.html", nil, "UTF-8") { |f| Nokogiri::HTML(f) }`

Answer (score -1):

nokogiri does weird stuff sometimes. I couldn't explain what nokogiri is "supposed" to do here -- both versions are 'correct' in representing the same thing in an HTML document.  Is it exactly the same version of nokogiri? If so, it could be a different version of libxml, which nokogiri uses under the hood, and in some cases will use an existing system install. Or the ruby 2.1 vs 2.3 difference could matter, although that seems unlikely.

Basically, if you want exactly the same behavior, you need to use exactly the same version of everything -- ruby, nokogiri, libxml.

The first is just the straight unicode bytes, the second has non-ascii characters replaced by html character entities. Both should be rendered the same in a browser. If you want one of those behaviors and not the other (personally I think I'd rather have the unicode), that's kind of a different question, but there's *probably* a way to force nokogiri to do it. But I don't know it.

If you use Nokogiri::XML instead of Nokogiri::HTML, I'd wager it won't replace non-ascii with html character entities, but you also, if I recall right, won't get some "forgiving of not quite legal syntax" behavior the HTML parser uses.

Wait, now looking closer, I'm thinking maybe the second one doesn't represent the same thing, it's html character entities, but I'm not sure they're really the right ones. Could encoding have gotten messed up? Depending on how you are reading the data in, and the OS, and what the LANG env variable is set to if it's a unix machine, it could be messing up the encoding.

Also, are you positive that the `Ina.html` file you are opening is really truly identical on both systems? Could it have become corrupted or transformed differently in the download process? Copy the file from one machine to the other to make sure the two files are really identical.

Comment: Nokogiri rarely does "weird stuff". It does what we tell it to do, so when we tell it to do weird things we get weird output.